# I can't get Material UI DatePicker to correctly parse UK dates

Tags: datepicker, localization, material-ui, locale

As I understand it, if I want the MUI DatePicker to correctly parse UK dates (day first, then month), I must pass the en-GB locale to MuiPickersUtilsProvider.  However, my attempts to do this are failing.

The code below..

```
import React from "react";
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from "@material-ui/pickers";
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import DatePicker from "./DatePicker2";
import enGB from "date-fns/locale/en-GB";

const App = () => (
  <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils} locale={enGB}>
    <DatePicker value={"2/4/2020"} />
  </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
);

export default App;
```

..will display the date "4 Feb 2020" when it should be displaying "2 Apr 2020".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example gist with locking pickers timezone to UTC. 
You can do exactly same with any other timezone https://gist.github.com/sibelius/37e7780c2a4a85ba1fea0b5cff196565

Answer (score 0):

This seems to relate to the native JS Date not parsing GB dates correctly.  The only way I can work out to fix this is to wrap the DatePicker in a GbDatePicker which parses the incoming string properly.  It feels verrrry hacky, so I'm interested in better ideas..

```
import { isValid } from 'date-fns';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { DatePicker as MuiDatePicker } from '@material-ui/pickers';

const GbDatePicker = (props) => {
  const { value, ...other } = props;
  const [intVal, setIntVal] = useState(value);
  const isSynced = intVal === value;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isSynced) {
      if (
        typeof value !== 'undefined' &&
        value !== null &&
        value !== '' &&
        isValid(new Date(value))
      ) {
        const delim = value.includes('/')
          ? /\//g
          : value.includes('-')
          ? '-'
          : value.includes(' ')
          ? ' '
          : null;
        if (delim !== null) {
          const parts = value.split(delim);
          if (parts.length === 3 && !isNaN(parts[1])) {
            setIntVal(new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]));
          } else {
            setIntVal(new Date(value));
          }
        } else {
          setIntVal(new Date(value));
        }
      }
    }
  }, [value, isSynced]);

  return <MuiDatePicker value={intVal} {...other} />;
};

export default GbDatePicker;
```